# Why does Aptana need Git installed on Windows?

Tags: php, git, aptana

Why does [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) need Git installed on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to [this](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/315-remove-the-git-dependency-from-studio-3) question on their support forum is probably what you are after.

Extract from linked site:

> Thank you for your interest in coming
>   back and your initial feedback. We use
>   git internally within the IDE for a
>   variety of purposes. Some user-visible
>   areas:
>
> 1) Downloading, editing, and
>   contributing back changes to Rubles,
>   our scripting interface. 2) Allowing
>   users to easily download templates and
>   samples that are remotely hosted
>
> I would not view it as a source
>   control system in this context, but
>   rather an program prerequisite. We
>   could have used a regular Java git
>   library, but we also use the git app
>   on Windows to provide good terminal
>   support too. We also could have
>   re-built the functionality ourselves,
>   but the git architecture and
>   infrastructure allows a lot of
>   flexibility that we can take advantage
>   of. You can choose not to install git,
>   but the above features won't work.
>
> There is a side benefit of allowing
>   users extremely easy setup of a source
>   control system without needing any
>   external servers, but users don't need
>   to interact with that if they have
>   another source control system they
>   like.
>
> Hope that explains our motivations a
>   bit better,